# How to create a binary dataframe with DatetimeIndex that states an event with date object as filters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of date objects, let's say `dates = ['2020-03-01', '2020-05-10']`, and a dataframe indexed with datetime object :

[image]

The dataset was generated from another one using the pandas resampling methods with "1h" as frequency.

I would like to fill the values of the column A and B using the list `dates` which contains date object.
More precisely, if an index is the same day as an element of `dates`, I want to put the corresponding row  and all 1-month previous rows with 1 as values. The other rows should be filled with 0 as values.

My strategy is to begin with an null dataframe sharing the columns and index of the initial one.
But I have some problems when I want to fill the values. In fact, I can do this using foor loop but I do believe in the fact that pandas is powerful enough to do this job with a few lines.

Can someone help me ? I would appreciate any help.

**Edit :**
To make the coding/testing easy I have changed a little bit the problem statement. The datetime index is now all the hours of the 2020-01-01.
The code below seems to work well but I do not see a way to iterate through the dates list without for loop... You can start from it.
Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datetime_index = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00:00', 
                           end='2020-01-01 23:59:59', freq='1h')
n_cols = 2
n_rows = datetime_index.size
df_shape =(n_rows, n_cols)

dates = ['2020-01-01 05:00:00']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=df_shape),
                  index = datetime_index.values,
                  columns = [f'column {i}' for i in range(n_cols)])

data = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(df_shape).astype(int),
                  index = datetime_index.values,
                  columns = [f'column {i}' for i in range(n_cols)])

data['column 0'] = data.apply(lambda x: int(x.name in pd.date_range(
                start=pd.to_datetime(dates[0]) - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='hours'),
                end=pd.to_datetime(dates[0]),
                freq='1h'
)), axis=1)
```

Comment: You should give an example that people can work on.

Comment: Sure, just a minute, I will provide it.

Comment: @user2640045 I have added a code to start from and it seems to work well. But, I don't see a way to iterate through dates without for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different version:

```
import pandas as pd

window = 30 # days
targets = ['2020-03-01', '2020-05-10']
dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-29', end='2020-07-01', freq='14d')

# create data frame
t = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)

# is target date close to i-th date?
for target in targets:
    t[target] = abs((t.index - pd.Timestamp(target)).days) < window
    
print(t.astype(int))

            2020-03-01  2020-05-10
2020-01-29           0           0
2020-02-12           1           0
2020-02-26           1           0
2020-03-11           1           0
2020-03-25           1           0
2020-04-08           0           0
2020-04-22           0           1
2020-05-06           0           1
2020-05-20           0           1
2020-06-03           0           1
2020-06-17           0           0
2020-07-01           0           0
```

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the freq to two weeks so I can check my result more easily

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

datetime_index = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00:00', 
                               end='2020-10-01 23:59:59', freq=f'{2*24*7}h')
n_cols = 2
n_rows = datetime_index.size
df_shape =(n_rows, n_cols)

dates = ['2020-03-01', '2020-05-10']

def to_datetime(x):
    year, month, day = map(int, x.split("-"))
    return datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)
dates = list(map(to_datetime, dates))

date_series = pd.Series(datetime_index, index=datetime_index)
pd.DataFrame({f"column{i}":date_series\
              .apply(lambda x:int(-pd.Timedelta(days=30)<(x-dates[i])<pd.Timedelta(days=30))) 
              for i in range(len(dates))})
```

this yields

```
            column0  column1
2020-01-01        0        0
2020-01-15        0        0
2020-01-29        0        0
2020-02-12        1        0
2020-02-26        1        0
2020-03-11        1        0
2020-03-25        1        0
2020-04-08        0        0
2020-04-22        0        1
2020-05-06        0        1
2020-05-20        0        1
2020-06-03        0        1
2020-06-17        0        0
2020-07-01        0        0
2020-07-15        0        0
2020-07-29        0        0
2020-08-12        0        0
2020-08-26        0        0
2020-09-09        0        0
2020-09-23        0        0
```

Comment: Your work done the job almost. In fact, in a given row, the values should be equal to a same and unique value (either 0 or 1). That makes me think that we don't need lot of columns.. it's just using memory for nothing interesting.

Comment: @kakarotto You're saying you want to combine the booleans (that the numbers are based on) with an &? You're making me think you should read this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html or watch this https://youtu.be/Pau9An-fQZk :).

Comment: @user2640045 I mean that the initial dataframe should be copied but its values should be either 0 and 1. If a row has an index that corresponds to one of the dates in the list, it should be set with 1, and all the 1-unit previous rows should be also set with 1 (where unit is initally a month, but it doesn't matter as it doesn't change the process). Anyway, thanks your answer with the answer of jsmart helped me to solve my problem. Thank you guys.